# how to add shared preferences to tic tac toe Android game?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sharedpreferences, tic-tac-toe

I have a tic tac toe game app created in a table layout with 9 buttons in three rows for the game, a textview which displays who's turn it is and a new game button at the bottom. 
I want to add shared preferences to the code so the game doesn't keep restarting if i swtich orientations. I know i need an onPause and onResume method but I am not sure what goes in the methods. Can someone please help with the methods to implement shared preferences? Below is most of the code for the game:

```
private SharedPreferences prefs;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tic_tac_toe);

    //get references to the widgets

    square1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.square1);
    square2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.square2);
    square3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.square3);
    square4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.square4);
    square5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.square5);
    square6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.square6);
    square7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.square7);
    square8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.square8);
    square9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.square9);

    messageTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.messageTextView);

   square1.setOnClickListener(this);
   square2.setOnClickListener(this);
   square3.setOnClickListener(this);
   square4.setOnClickListener(this);
   square5.setOnClickListener(this);
   square6.setOnClickListener(this);
   square7.setOnClickListener(this);
   square8.setOnClickListener(this);
   square9.setOnClickListener(this);

   prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
};



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

protected void onPause(){


}

public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();


}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    boolean flag;
    String lbl = messageTextView.getText().toString();
    Button btn = (Button) v;

    if (btn.getText().toString().equals("")){
        if (lbl.equals("Player X\'s turn")){
            btn.setText("X");
            messageTextView.setText("Player O\'s turn");
        }

        else{
            btn.setText("0");
            messageTextView.setText("Player X\'s turn");
        }
    }

    flag = determineWinner();

    if (!flag){
        checkAgain();
    }

}



public boolean determineWinner(){
    if (square1.getText().toString().equals("X") &&
            square2.getText().toString().equals("X")
            && square3.getText().toString().equals("X"))
    {
        message = "Player X wins";
        messageTextView.setText(message);   
        disableButtons();
        return true;

    }

    if (square1.getText().toString().equals("X")
            && square4.getText().toString().equals("X")
            && square7.getText().toString().equals("X"))

    {

        message = "Player X wins";
        messageTextView.setText(message);   
        disableButtons();
        return true;

    }

    if (square4.getText().toString().equals("X")
            && square5.getText().toString().equals("X")
            && square6.getText().toString().equals("X"))

    {

        message = "Player X wins";
        messageTextView.setText(message);   
        disableButtons();
        return true;

    }

    if (square7.getText().toString().equals("X")
            && square8.getText().toString().equals("X")
            && square9.getText().toString().equals("X"))

    {

        message = "Player X wins";
        messageTextView.setText(message);   
        disableButtons();
        return true;

    }

    if (square2.getText().toString().equals("X")
            && square5.getText().toString().equals("X")
            && square8.getText().toString().equals("X"))

    {

        message = "Player X wins";
        messageTextView.setText(message);   
        disableButtons();
        return true;

    }

    if (square3.getText().toString().equals("X")
            && square6.getText().toString().equals("X")
            && square9.getText().toString().equals("X"))

    {

        message = "Player X wins";
        messageTextView.setText(message);   
        disableButtons();
        return true;

    }

    if (square1.getText().toString().equals("X")
            && square5.getText().toString().equals("X")
            && square9.getText().toString().equals("X"))

    {

        message = "Player X wins";
        messageTextView.setText(message);   
        disableButtons();
        return true;

    }

    if (square3.getText().toString().equals("X")
            && square5.getText().toString().equals("X")
            && square7.getText().toString().equals("X"))

    {

        message = "Player X wins";
        messageTextView.setText(message);   
        disableButtons();
        return true;

    }

    if (square1.getText().toString().equals("0")
            && square2.getText().toString().equals("0")
            && square3.getText().toString().equals("0"))

    {

        message = "Player O wins";
        messageTextView.setText(message);   
        disableButtons();
        return true;

    }

    if (square4.getText().toString().equals("0")
            && square5.getText().toString().equals("0")
            && square6.getText().toString().equals("0"))

    {

        message = "Player O wins";
        messageTextView.setText(message);   
        disableButtons();
        return true;

    }

    if (square7.getText().toString().equals("0")
            && square8.getText().toString().equals("0")
            && square9.getText().toString().equals("0"))

    {

        message = "Player O wins";
        messageTextView.setText(message);   
        disableButtons();
        return true;

    }

    if (square1.getText().toString().equals("0")
            && square4.getText().toString().equals("0")
            && square7.getText().toString().equals("0"))

    {

        message = "Player O wins";
        messageTextView.setText(message);   
        disableButtons();
        return true;

    }

    if (square2.getText().toString().equals("0")
            && square5.getText().toString().equals("0")
            && square8.getText().toString().equals("0"))

    {

        message = "Player O wins";
        messageTextView.setText(message);   
        disableButtons();
        return true;

    }

    if (square3.getText().toString().equals("0")
            && square6.getText().toString().equals("0")
            && square9.getText().toString().equals("0"))

    {

        message = "Player O wins";
        messageTextView.setText(message);   
        disableButtons();
        return true;

    }

    if (square1.getText().toString().equals("0")
            && square5.getText().toString().equals("0")
            && square9.getText().toString().equals("0"))

    {

        message = "Player O wins";
        messageTextView.setText(message);   
        disableButtons();
        return true;

    }

    if (square3.getText().toString().equals("0")
            && square5.getText().toString().equals("0")
            && square7.getText().toString().equals("0"))

    {

        message = "Player O wins";
        messageTextView.setText(message);   
        disableButtons();
        return true;

    }

    return false;

}
```

Comment: `I want to add shared preferences to the code so the game doesn't keep restarting if i swtich orientations.` - Why would your game restart on orientation change?

Comment: I wouldn't use SharedPreferences, but the onPause/onResume mechanism, instead.

Comment: I don't know why the game restarts when i change orientation

Comment: It is default android behavior http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

Answer (score 0):

For example

```
@override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    square1.setText(pref.getString("square1", ""));
    square1.setTag("square1"); // you can define view tag in xml layout
    /*
     * to square9
     */
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    pref.edit().putString((String)v.getTag(),currentPlayer).commit();
    if (currentPlayer.equal("X")
        currentPlayer = "O";
    else
        currentPlayer = "X";
}
```

and don't forget to reset value before start a new game

Comment: thanks for the code example. But I don't have a variable for currentPlayer so would the variable message work there? also where do I need to call this onResume method in the code?

Comment: the game still restarts when i change orientation

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution I see is that you use fragments to build your app. Once you've implemented a single fragment activity (basically an activity that just loads your fragment within its layout) and the fragment you have just to call `this.setRetainInstance(true)` in the fragment `onCreateView` method (overridden). 
The only difference that matters in this particular case between fragment and activity is that the view is not created in `onCreate` with a `setContentView` but in  `onCreateView`. Anyway there are tons of examples online.